# How do I get WordPress' REST API to include user metadata?

Tags: wordpress, rest

I've set up a WordPress site and added a couple of users. When I look directly in the `wp_usermeta` table in the database, there are several records there, so the users do also have some metadata.

According to [the documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/users/), `meta` should be included when requesting users, but when I request `/wp-json/wp/v2/users` all the `meta` fields are an empty array.

What am I missing? How can I get metadata about users through the REST API?

Comment: maybe this is useful: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Comment: @FooBar Not really; that only shows how to get the metadata from within the WordPress instance. I want to fetch it through the [REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/).

Comment: did you figure this out ?

Comment: @PouyaAtaei: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44696339/38055

Comment: that doesn't work for me....

Answer (score 6):

I managed to find an even easier way to accomplish this, based on [this part of the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/).

Not sure where it's best practice to put this code. Since I already have an API-related plugin, I just added the code there.

```
// legend:    <type>, <meta_key>, <config>
register_meta('user', 'nickname', array(
  "type" => "string",
  "show_in_rest" => true // this is the key part
));
```

Now I just have to figure out which specific keys I need :)

Answer (score 0):

***This is not mine, founded at:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270154/getting-user-meta-data-from-wp-rest-api***

Wrote here for future reference into StackOverflow:

Look into **register_rest_field()** to register meta with the rest api.

```
   add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'adding_user_meta_rest' );

    function adding_user_meta_rest() {
       register_rest_field( 'user',
                            'collapsed_widgets',
                             array(
                               'get_callback'      => 'user_meta_callback',
                               'update_callback'   => null,
                               'schema'            => null,
                                )
                          );
    }
```

And then put your **get_user_meta** bit in the callback.

```
function user_meta_callback( $user, $field_name, $request) {
       return get_user_meta( $user[ 'id' ], $field_name, true );
   }
```

The **WP_REST_Meta_Fields** class may provide more useful insight as well.

---

**Update: on registering custom routes**

A quick and dirty partial example. Cobbled out of some stuff sitting in front of me, but it is not a working example.

May help as you read through docs. Follow the connection between the first **register_rest_route**, it's GET method's callback, **my_get_callback**, below, and the callback method's use of the **WP_Rest_Request class**. It should help to draw a connection of the steps. The docs I mentioned in the comments will get into other args, params, etc., and of course the **permissions_callback** stuff.

Hope it helps.

```
   class My_Extend_Rest extends WP_REST_Controller {
            public function __construct() {
                add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'register_routes' ) );
            }//end __construct

            public function register_routes() {
                $version = '1';
                $namespace = 'my-fancy-namespace/v' . $version; 
                $base = 'my-route-base';

    // so, site.com/wp-json/my-fancy-namespace/v2/my-route-base/

                register_rest_route( $namespace, '/'. $base, array(
                    array(
                        'methods'  => 'GET',
                        'callback' => array( $this, 'my_get_callback' ),
                        'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'key_permissions_check' ),
                        ),
                    array(
                        'methods'  => 'POST',
                        'callback' => array( $this, 'my_post_callback' ),
                        'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'key_permissions_check' ),
                        ),)
                );

                $base2 = 'my-second-base';
    // so, site.com/wp-json/my-fancy-namespace/v2/my-second-base/

                register_rest_route( $namespace, '/'. $base2, array(
                    array(
                        'methods'  => 'GET',
                        'callback' => array( $this, 'my_get_callback_two' ),
                        'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'key_permissions_check' ),
                        ),
                    array(
                        'methods'  => 'POST',
                        'callback' => array( $this, 'my_post_callback_two' ),
                        'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'key_permissions_check' ),
                        ),)
                );

        }//register_routes

       public function key_permissions_check() {
          //do permissions check stuff
       }

       public function my_get_callback( WP_REST_Request $request ) {

            //do stuff with $request 
           //see the methods mentioned in the comment




        }//end 
}//end class
```